# Frequency histogram in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I am trying to read the frequency histogram of cards. When I execute the program with the input `3D3D3S`, it shows `3D` occurs 3 times. Could anybody help me explain what did I do wrong? It only reads the number and ignores the suit of the card.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct card
{
  enum class suit { club, spade, diamond, heart };
  enum { ace=1, jack=10, queen=11, king=12 };
  using number = int;

  number num_;
  suit suit_;
};

int main()
{

        card mycards;
        map<card, unsigned> freqhist;
        while(cin >> mycards)
        {
        auto[pos,is_added] = freqhist.insert({mycards,1});
        if (!is_added)
            ++pos->second;
        }
        cout << "FreqHist results:\n";
        for (auto const& elem : freqhist)
                 cout << elem.first << " occurs " << elem.second << " times \n";

}
```

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: If you have `jack=10`, then what is the value of an actual 10-card ? :)

Comment: The value of jack and 10-card will be the same. So both will be 10 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map` doesn't need `==` operator to distinguish uniqueness (your code will actually compile if your remove the `==` definition). It solely relies on the `<` operator, this means:

```
bool operator <(card const& a, card const& b)
{
  return a.num_ < b.num_;
}
```

...when used with `3S` and `3D`, it will only compare the `num_` values only, meaning **3**S will naturally be equals to **3**D. Notice that it will work as intended when you insert {`1S`, `2S`, `3S`}.

To fix this, you can modify your `<` condition to compare between `_suit` values when `num_`s are equal:

```
bool operator <(card const& a, card const& b)
{
    if (a.num_ == b.num_) {
        return b.suit_ < a.suit_;
    }
    return a.num_ < b.num_;
}
```

BTW, you don't need to check the value returned from `freqhist::insert` to count the frequency, you can simply do it with:

```
while(cin >> mycards) {
    freqhist[mycards]++;
}
```

Final run:

```
3S3S3D


FreqHist results:
3D occurs 1 times 
3S occurs 2 times
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain why does it return b.suit_< a.suit_ instead a.suit_< b.suit?

Comment: @Vivian `a.suit_< b.suit` will sort ascendingly by `suit_`'s order in `{ club, spade, diamond, heart }` and vice versa. There is no difference unless you care about that ordering while traversing `freqhist`.